# Error when converting dynamic type -- Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#

I am trying to write expression trees to dynamically build LINQ. I have a client-side grid with server-side lazy loading of grid data. The grid requests rows which includes a filter model in the request resource. A given property of my request resource can have multiple types depending on which column is being filtered.

I've search SO and found some similar posts, but they didn't quite cover my exact setup/issues -- as most of the answers were more focused on using `Convert.ChangeType` or using the `dynamic`, both of which I'm already using.

Here is the FilterModel:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Values { get; set; }
}
```

So some example requests would be:

Filter on a set of ids:

```
{
    type: "set"
    values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Filter on a set of categories:

```
{
    type: "set"
    values: ["Category_1", "Category_3"]
}
```

where the type of each record in `values` is determined by the type of the property of row object's corresponding column.

**The error and the code:**

I'm getting an error when trying to convert to the Row object column's property type: `System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.`

Setup:

```
FilterModel filter = new FilterModel() { Type = "set", Values = [1, 2, 3, 4] };

ParameterExpression rowModelParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RowModel));

string propertyName = "id"; // "category"
PropertyInfo property = typeof(RowModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;

MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(rowModelParameterExpression , property);
```

Conversion logic **(the error is in this code)**:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { propertyType });
MethodInfo contains = listType.GetMethod("Contains", new[] { propertyType });
Expression comparisonValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(filter.Values, listType));

Expression predicateBody = Expression.Call(comparisonValue, contains, propertyExpression);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not convert/cast `IEnumerable<dynamic>` to `List<sometype>` directly. I suggest you converting it to array and use `Enumerable.Contains<T>` method for predicate. Something like this:

```
FilterModel filter = new FilterModel() { Type = "set", Values = new dynamic[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
ParameterExpression rowModelParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RowModel));

string propertyName = "id"; // "category"
PropertyInfo property = typeof(RowModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;

MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(rowModelParameterExpression, property);

MethodInfo contains = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
    .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Contains" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Single()
    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { propertyType });


var values = filter.Values.Select(i => Convert.ChangeType(i, propertyType)).ToArray();
var arr = Array.CreateInstance(propertyType, values.Length);
Array.Copy(values, arr, values.Length);

Expression comparisonValue = Expression.Constant(arr);

Expression predicateBody = Expression.Call(null, contains, comparisonValue, propertyExpression);
```

Comment: @xb4rrm27m5 was glad to help!